# MySQL - Error 1823: Failed to add the foreign key constraint to system tables

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm updating a database to correct the foreign key behaviour on update and delete. However, on one table in particular this has been unexpectedly difficult.

On most tables, I've been doing the following without any issues:

1. Drop the foreign key constraint
2. Drop the corresponding index
3. Add a new, updated foreign key

One table, however, is causing some trouble I can't quite understand. Trying to do the process above returns the following error (I've redacted the DB name to `db_name`):

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1025 Error on rename of 
'./<db_name>/#sql-5e1_1c5' to './<db_name>/doctors' 
(errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)
(SQL: alter table `doctors` drop index `doctors_id_unique`)
```

The relevant part of the table is as follows, initially

```
  UNIQUE KEY `doctors_id_unique` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `doctors_code_unique` (`code`),
  KEY `doctors_updated_by_foreign` (`updated_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `doctors_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `doctors_updated_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

I want to change `id` to a primary key *and* foreign key, so I do the following:

```
ALTER TABLE doctors DROP FOREIGN KEY doctors_id_foreign;
ALTER TABLE doctors DROP INDEX doctors_code_unique;
ALTER TABLE doctors DROP INDEX doctors_id_unique;
```

On that 3rd statement, however, I get the following error:

```
Error on rename of './<db_name>/#sql-5e1_2' to './<db_name>/doctors' 
(errno: 150 - Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed)
```

I can't figure out how to fix that. I try dropping the `updated_by` constraint and key as well as the `code` unique key first, but it doesn't change anything. I try disabling foreign key checks, but no cigar.

I try changing the SQL dump I had been using for tests. Changing it to the following made it work as I had intended, at least apparently:

```
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `doctors_code_unique` (`code`),
  KEY `doctors_updated_by_foreign` (`updated_by`),
  CONSTRAINT `doctors_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `doctors_updated_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

However, I would rather update the table programatically so I can make the migration more easily and reliably. So I try a different approach and just rename the table, copy it sans keys to a new one, and add the keys there:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
RENAME TABLE `doctors` TO `old_doctors`;
CREATE TABLE `doctors` SELECT * FROM `old_doctors`;
ALTER TABLE `doctors` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `doctors` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `doctors_code_unique` (`code`);
ALTER TABLE `doctors` ADD CONSTRAINT `doctors_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY `doctors_id_foreign` (`id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE `doctors` ADD CONSTRAINT `doctors_updated_by_foreign` FOREIGN KEY `doctors_updated_by_foreign` (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

And now I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1823 Failed to add the foreign key constraint
'<db_name>/doctors_id_foreign' to system tables (SQL: ALTER TABLE `doctors`
ADD CONSTRAINT `doctors_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY `doctors_id_foreign` (`id`) 
REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)
```

So I just can't get it to work, and neither error seems to be common: I couldn't find any good information on how to deal with either of them.

This has been so time-consuming that I'm probably going to put the servers down, dump the DB, fix the dump manually and import the fixed dump back; however, I'd really like to know if this is some bug or if I'm just missing something. Which is highly likely, because I'm hardly an experienced programmer.

For context: this is all on a Laravel (5.7.13) project, but the errors happen both using Laravel migrations (with Schema and Blueprint) and directly through the SQL console. MySQL version 5.7.22.

**tl;dr:** I just can't change a table's foreign key's behaviour on update/delete, despite doing so successfully on various other tables on the same DB. I tried two vastly different approaches to fixing it, and both returned (distinct) errors, resolutions of which I couldn't find anywhere. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Please provide an SQL dump of the table's state before you alter the foreign keys. Are any other tables referencing this table in their foreign keys?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir The issue was with the other tables referencing this table's ID: I changed the migration to 1) remove the foreign keys referencing `doctors.id`; 2) update the `doctors` table; 3) restore the foreign keys that reference `doctors.id` and it finally worked. Could you post that as an answer so I can flag it? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that no other tables are referencing the `doctors.id` column in their foreign keys.

If they are, remove those foreign keys before you drop the `doctors_id_unique` index.

Then restore the foreign keys after you have made `doctors.id` the primary key.

Comment: That fixed it! IMO the error messages could have been clearer, but I should have known the issue could be on that column being referenced by other tables' foreign keys. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 5.X, I've also run into the error:

> Error Code: 1823. Failed to add the foreign key constraint `'<database>/<foreign_key>'` to system tables

When I've tried to create a table with a duplicate foreign key identifier to one that already existed elsewhere in the database (e.g. a backup of the table with the same keys). For some reason, the above error came up instead of the expected:

> Error Code: 1826. Duplicate foreign key constraint name `'<database>/<foreign_key>'`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somebody will have the same root cause.
I tried to create a foreign key with the already existing name of the foreign key in another table.
So I just edit the name of the foreign key and it was created successfully.